# Drupal image disappears

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, zurb-foundation

I have a problem with an image on top of my page.
When the `url` is websitename/menu, the `image` is shown.
When the `url` is websitename/node/164, the `image` disappears.

So the `image` is shown when the level is 1, but when the `url-level` is higher than 1, the `image` disappears.

I am using the `ZURB-Foundation` theme on `Drupal-7`. 
Here is the code I use in `page.tpl.php`

```
<!--.page -->
<div role="document" class="page">
<?php
// Create a variable to hold the full path, in our theme, to the image.
//   path_to_theme() takes care of creating the correct path for the active theme (which is  likely your own custom one)
$my_static_banners = path_to_theme() . '/images/header/';
?>
<?php
if ($handle = opendir(path_to_theme() . '/images/header')) {
/* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */

while (false !== ($picture = readdir($handle))) {
  if($picture != "." && $picture != ".."){
    $pictures[] = $picture;
  }
}
$random = array_rand($pictures,1);
$header_picture = $pictures[$random];
closedir($handle);
}
?>
<!-- MENU-->
<!--.l-header region -->
<header role="banner" class="l-header" >
<div class="header-image" style="background-image:url(<?php print     $my_static_banners.$header_picture ?>)">
</div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try and reduce the amount of php code within your theming layer.

Within your page template:

```
<div role="document" class="page">
<!-- MENU-->
<!--.l-header region -->
<header role="banner" class="l-header" >
  <div class="header-image" style="background-image:url(<?php print $header_image; ?>);">
  </div>
  </div>
```

Within your template.php in the theme or within a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['header_image'] = FALSE;
  $images = _THEME_NAME_get_images();
  if ($images) {
    $random = array_rand($images, 1);
    $variables['header_image'] = $images[$random];
  }
}

/**
 * Get images within a particular director.
 *
 * @return array
 *   An array of images for the header.
 */
function _THEME_NAME_get_images() {
  $dir = drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME') . '/images/header';
  $images = array();
  if (is_dir($dir) && $handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (FALSE !== ($filename = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($filename[0] != '.') {
        $images[] = $dir . $filename;
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
  return $images;
}
```

Comment: I get an arror: Notice: Undefined variable: header_image in include() (line 27 of C:\wamp\www\raedthuijs\sites\all\themes\foundation_raedthuijs\templates\page.tpl.php)

Comment: This happens when the preprocess isn't being called, ensure the THEME_NAME is replaced for your hook, either the name of the theme in which you have placed this code in or the module 'namespace'. Once you have this clear your cache. Try putting a var_dump($variables); die(); within the hook_preprocess_page() implementation, as soon as your page dies you know that the hook is being implemented.

Comment: Thanks, this works, i don't know what i did wrong first, but now it works. I think it workes now because I cleared my cache. But the picture still disappears when i go to an url like /node/290.
When I inspect the code, the right url is placed in the code, but no image appears

Comment: Can you send over an example of the html output?

Comment: When i surf to http://localhost:81/raedthuijs/node/287
=> http://pastebin.com/g5dY3T61
When I surf to http://localhost:81/raedthuijs/overons
=> http://pastebin.com/Rgkz40z0